# Visual force page not able to generate buttons

Tags: visualforce, community, custom-button

I am trying to generate a custom button on custom object `Offer`. But this is giving me error 
"you must enter a value" in content picklist.

[image]

I searched several posts. But related to content I am not getting relevant info, '
How to set value for Content field?'

Comment: Can you share you visualforce page code here?

Comment: I think you need to change the Content Source and select URL then set your Visualforce page there

Comment: Content Source  is blank . thats my question that what to write in code to map in content list

Comment: @neeraj see my answer and let me know if it solve your problem

Answer (score 4):

If you need your developed Visualforce there in 'Content' then that page must have the attribute `StandardController` otherwise that visualforce will not show up here as 'Content'

for example - Custom Object is : Offer

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Offer__c" extensions="OfferController">
       -------
</apex:pages>
```

Apex Class

```
public class OfferController{

       public OfferController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
             ---------
       }
}
```

Let me know if this will help you out